# Django Javascript append options

Tags: javascript, python, django, get, tuples

In my class in models.py I have a field:

```
names = models.TextField(max_length=40, choices=sektor, default="Adam", verbose_name="Name")

sektor = (
    ("Adam", "Adam"),
    ("Tom", "Tom"),
)
```

When I change an option in my page, I run the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var endpoint = '/call_jquery_sektor/'
        var sektor = []
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            success: function(data){
                sektor = data.sektor
                //loop
                $(sektor).each(function(i) {
                $("#id_names").append("<option>" + sektor[i] + "</option>") //append options
                })
                },
            error: function(error_data){
                console.log("error")
                console.log(error_data)
                }
        })
    </script>
```

I get all data, writen as two elements of each tuple, in one row. I would like to clear all previous options and when I run script I would get list of all names, each name single time and only 1 in 1 row.

I get:

```
Adam, Adam, Tom, Tom
```

I would like to get:

```
Adam
Tom
```

Comment: call `$(#id_names).empty();` before `$(sektor).each(function(i`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply by adding this line in your code!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var endpoint = '/call_jquery_sektor/'
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(data){
            var sektor = []
            sektor = data.sektor
            //loop
            $(sektor).each(function(i) {
            $("#id_names").append("<option>" + sektor[i] + "</option>") //append options
            })
            },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
            }
    })
</script>
```